# How to uniquely characterize an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it possible to characterize an integer array in C++? Once characterized, arrays containing same set of elements will have same characteristics.
I was thinking on lines of *hashcode*, each hashcode will uniquely identify an array!

For example `ary[]={4,5,3,2,4}` and `ary_two[]={4,4,2,3,5}` should both have same characteristics/ hashcode!

I am trying to solve this question( asked in an interview ): A number of variable sized arrays are being generated. For each array determine if we have encountered an array before containing the same elements as this array!

Comment: With a hash code of any kind, you must also consider the possibility of hash collision.

Comment: can you please give an example of hash code in c++?

Comment: Hash functions exist outside any particular programming language. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: well I am well aware about hash functions. For programming in c++ in say interview questions or programming competitions, I use MAP as a substitute for hash. But is there any way I can generate a 'value' that corresponds to the array!

Comment: One way can be map entire array element->element_count and then use second map to find if the identical map exists. But it will be very time and memory consuming.

Comment: Sort the array. The sorted array is your "unique characteristic".

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to use the elements hashes themselves (assuming the content of the array is hashable). Then just fold them together with some suitable function (e.g. an `xor` or better yet `+`). Make sure the folding function is commutative and associative, or the order of the array will make a difference.

Comment: That's a poor hash function, because two arrays containing `[1, 1]` and `[2, 2]` would hash to the same value (zero) after xoring the individual element hashes.

Comment: @GregHewgill: The xor was just from the top of my head. You could also use a `+` instead. As you say yourself, there will always be collisions (but I agree on your observation that xor might be particularly poor, here).

Comment: It is an integer array. I am sorry but I dont understand what you mean by 'elements hashes'.

Comment: @Tag318: Each element of your array (i.e. 4,5,3,...) can be hashed individually with `std::hash` which leaves the question open how you compute a hash from a collection of hashes. My suggestion was to use some operation `op` like `xor` or `+`: `op(std::hash<int>()(4),std::hash<int>(op(std::hash<int>()(5),...))`.

Comment: ohh thanks, yes it might work. So I just found out 'std::hash' is there in c++11 the most recent version of c++! maybe we can sort the array and then use 'std::hash' to hash the entire array. If we are able to do that our purpose might be solved!

Comment: @Tag318: As I said, if your folding function is commutative and associative (like `+` is) you don't **have to** sort the array.

Answer (score 2):

Investigate [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). You can probably overload it to do what you want. For instance, if you want the arrays with values `{4, 5, 3, 2, 4}` and `{4, 4, 2, 3, 5}` to hash to the same value, you could specialize it like this:

```
template<> struct hash<std::array<int, 5>>
{
    size_t operator()(const std::array<int, 5> &ary) const
    {
        return std::accumulate(std::begin(ary), std::end(ary), 0U) * 16777619;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank You, I will explore std::hash and try to find a solution!